# Sending messages to Faust topic from local file / List

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-asyncio, faust

I want to be able to either consume messages from a Kafka broker or a local file with data in it. How do I do this with Faust without writing a very similar function without Faust that just uses a simple for loop to iterate over messages?

Or is it better to just avoid Faust in this case? Still learning all of this, not sure if this should be even done.

```
@app.agent(input_topic)
async def myagent(messages):
    async for item in stream:
        result = do_something(item)
        await output_topic.send(result)
```

How do I modify this code block to be able to accept messages from a given file/list as well (depending on a config variable that will be set)? Or to send the messages from a file/list to the input topic?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you don't need Faust. (Plus, it can't read files).

Use `kafka-python`, `aiokafka`, etc. Use `open('file')` like you would with any other file, and read it, then produce data from it

Answer (score 0):

If you need stateful processing, [bytewax](https://github.com/bytewax/bytewax) is a good option instead of Faust because of the flexibility of inputs.